# Regression with multiple dependent variables controlling for age and gender

Tags: regression, spss, multivariate-regression

I have multiple dependent variables (interval) and one independent variable (interval). I would also like to control for age (interval) and sex (categorical). Is this possible in SPSS?

Moreover, my sample consists of 3 different groups and I would like to see if there's a difference between the groups in the prediction of my multiple dependent variables from my single independent variable.

I appreciate any help,
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a MANOVA where you include the interaction between the three groups and the other predictors. See [here](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/manova-in-spss/) for more.

Comment: Sorry, I used wrong review excerpt. Should be: We are trying to build a permanent repository of high-quality statistical information in the form of questions & answers. Thus, we're wary of link-only answers, due to linkrot. Can you post a summary of the information at the link, in case it goes dead?

Comment: Thank you! Analyze - GLM - multivariate. Fixed factors: control variable gender and the grouping variable. Covariates: predictor of interest and control variable age.
Or would gender also have to go under covariates? Did I also understand correctly that I would include interaction effects for my predictor of interest with both control variables (gender, age) as well as with the grouping variable in the 'model' option?What about performing the analysis three times separately for each group?

Comment: @Sun if you perform the analysis separately for each group, you fit 3 different models and you will not have a test of how a model discriminates.. you will just observe different models with different coefficients, but you will not test

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control for additional variables in a multivariate regression, then just add those variables to regressors. For the test you mention see the answer of @AndroidApp above

Comment: Thank you, please see my additional questions above.